# Add a character on each line of a string

Tags: c#, character, line, addition

I make a CSV converter, for this, I need to replace all the spaces with ";". I have already did this step. The problem is that I have a texbox with the multiline mod. Here is my actual code :

```
string[] Espace1 = new string[] { " " };
foreach (string contenu in content1.Split(Espace1, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    content1 = content1.Replace(" ", ";");
    File.WriteAllText(path1, content1);
}
```

Here is the output : (an example)

```
15;16;13;21
15;49;47
46;78;15
```

So that the file is well interprets like a csv I need to add a ";" at the end of each line. Like :

```
15;16;13;21;
15;49;47;
46;78;15;
```

Any help ? :)

**EDIT**

Here is my complete code :

```
        string nom = tbxNom.Text;
        #region Normal
        try
        {
            string content1 = tbxArret.Text;
            string path1 = @"C:\Users\DanyWin\Desktop\CsvOutput\" + nom + ".csv";
            string[] Espace1 = new string[] { " " };
            foreach (string contenu in content1.Split(Espace1, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                content1 = content1.Replace(" ", ";");
                File.WriteAllText(path1, content1);
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            lblInfo.Text = "Erreur";
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment by accident. The question was, whether content1 contains all lines

Comment: Yes it contains all the lines here I just split all the space to replace them by ";"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`content1` seems to contain the whole file.

So if you want to add semicolons to each line, you could replace the newline with a semicolon and a newline.

```
content1 = content1.Replace("\n", ";\n");
```

---

You can make your code a bit easier:

```
string nom = tbxNom.Text;
#region Normal
try
{
    string content1 = tbxArret.Text;
    string path1 = @"C:\Users\DanyWin\Desktop\CsvOutput\" + nom + ".csv";
    var lines = content1.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @"\s+", ";") + ";");
    content1 = String.Join("\n", lines);
    File.WriteAllText(path1, content1);
}
catch
{
    lblInfo.Text = "Erreur";
}
```

Comment: that is not correct.  firstly, the spaces are replaced by ;.  only those at end of line need additional semi color and new line

Comment: @MPavlak thats why the newline is prepended with a semicolon. I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: the first replacement is to change space into semi colon.  that is not done here

Comment: @MPavlak yea, I left that out since he already figured out how to do that

Comment: @Domysee Here is my output if I use your code :
15;69;78
;
15;16;48
That does not affect all the entries. That's why I use a foreach loop

Comment: @Dany could you post what content1 contains before replacing the spaces?

Answer (score 0):

```
content1 = string.Concat( content1.Replace(" ", ";"), ";");
```

Remove all spaces then concat ";" at end

Comment: It puts all the ";" at the end :

15;19;17
15;17;18;156;;;;;;

Answer (score 0):

```
char []split = new char[]{' '};

//replaces all " " with ";", contiguous "    " will be replaced with a single ";"
var c2 = String.Join(";", content1.Split(split, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)); 

//replaces all newlines with a semicolon followed by a newline, thus appends a semicolon to the end of line. 
var c3 = c2.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, ";"+System.Environment.NewLine);

//If the file did not end with an NewLine, append a semicolon to the last line
if (!c3.EndsWith(System.Environment.NewLine)) c3+=";";

File.WriteAllText(path, c3);
```

It's not the fastest solution, but it works.

Comment: No. The first line takes care of all spaces.