# Delete character at nth position for each line in a text file

Tags: c#, regex, file, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

I have multiple text files in folder. I need to delete character at the 8th character of each line in the text files. Text files have 100+ multiple rows

How would I conduct this?

Original file example:

```
123456789012345....
abcdefghijklmno....
```

New file:

```
12345679012345
abcdefgijklmno
```

Reading this article is helpful:

[Add a character on each line of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36044775/add-a-character-on-each-line-of-a-string)

Note: Length of text lines can be variable (not sure if it matters- one row can have 20 characters, next line may have 30 characters, etc.
All text files are in folder: C:\TestFolder

Similar question:
[Insert character at nth position for each line in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55876939/insert-character-at-nth-position-for-each-line-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `File.ReadAllLines()` and `string.Substring()` methods as follwing:

```
string path = @"C:\TestFolder";
string charToInsert = " ";
string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly); //Directory.EnumerateFiles
foreach (string file in allFiles)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file); //input file
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(line.Length > 8 ? line.Substring(0, 7) + line.Substring(8) : line);
    }
    File.WriteAllText(file, sb.ToString()); //overwrite modified content
}
```

- `line.Substring(0, 7)` means first 7 characters (char #0 to #6 with length of 7).
- `line.Substring(8)` means from 9'th character to end (char #8 to end).

Note that char positions are zero-indexed!